Power Query: after combining 2 tables got something strange
I have a column in which each value is repeated twice. And each value has its own share (input data). I need to calculate the average share among the first occurrence of values in the first column and the average for the second occurrence, for each subgroup (the subgroups are distinguished by the first part of the name: like input car 1, car 1, car 2, car 2, bike 1, bike 1, bike 2, bike 2, etc (word + number). An example is shown in the figure.To do this, I created an occurrence index. However, when I combine data from the new table with indexes and the old table with weeks and shares, I get something strange: each value from the first column is now repeated not twice, but four times. How can I fix this?
It is also worth noting that I need the average not for the entire column, but for each subgroup of the column.
I created an occurrence index as suggested here: link
Right click, Group By, keep name, use operation All Rows
Change the code in the window from
= Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Group ID"}, {{"Count", each , type table ....
to
= Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Group ID"}, {{"Count", each Table.AddIndexColumn(_, "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type), type table}})

you can try this in PQ to create the index column and new name column
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Name", type text}, {"Share", type number}}),
    Custom1 = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Name"}, {{"Count", each Table.AddIndexColumn(_, "Index", 1, 1, Int64.Type), type table}}),
    #"Expanded Count" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Custom1, "Count", {"Share", "Index"}, {"Share", "Index"}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded Count", "Name2", each Text.Remove([Name],{"0".."9"}))
in
    #"Added Custom"


then you can create a calculated column in PP
=CALCULATE(AVERAGE([Share]),ALLEXCEPT(Table1_1,Table1_1[Name2],Table1_1[Index]))



I tried to add a column in the sample data
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"share", type number}}),
    Custom1 = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Name"}, {{"Count", each Table.AddIndexColumn(_, "Index", 1, 1, Int64.Type), type table}}),
    #"Expanded Count" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Custom1, "Count", {"column", "share", "Index"}, {"column", "share", "Index"})
in
    #"Expanded Count"



Thank you very much!  I also have other columns in the table (I just didn't add them in the picture for simplicity). I created an index as you suggested. But, unfortunately,  my other columns started looking weird (similar to the 3rd table in the picture). Is there a way to avoid modifying other columns?

i have updated my answer. Pls see the last part, i have added one column and get the output.

I did it and indeed got the result. But then I noticed that in the table there are much more rows now: I had 7k rows, now I have a million and after 7k it again shows the first row, the second row etc

I figured out! I went to editor, clicked on Table icon in front of the 1st column header, clicked 'Keep Top rows' and entered a number. Thank you!!!!! I wonder I'd there is another way to solve the problem, cause getting a million rows can be complicated on my personal PC (not more powerful  PC from work)

Is there a way to create the calculated column of average shares without using PP, but using Power Query?

You could do it all at once in powerquery, preserving any additional columns
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table4"]}[Content],
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Index2", 0, 1, Int64.Type), //for resorting at end can be removed
#"Inserted Modulo" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Index", each Number.Mod([Index2], 2), type number),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Inserted Modulo", "Prefix", each Text.BeforeDelimiter([Name], " ")),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Added Custom", {"Index", "Prefix"}, {{"Average Share", each List.Average([Share]), type nullable number}, {"data", each _, type table}}),
ColumnsToExpand  =List.RemoveItems(List.Distinct(List.Combine(List.Transform(Table.Column(#"Grouped Rows", "data"), each if _ is table then Table.ColumnNames(_) else {}))),Table.ColumnNames(#"Grouped Rows")),
#"Expanded data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(   #"Grouped Rows", "data",ColumnsToExpand,ColumnsToExpand),
#"Sorted Rows" = Table.Buffer(Table.Sort(#"Expanded data",{{"Index2", Order.Ascending}})), //resorts, can be removed
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Sorted Rows",{"Index2", "Prefix"})
in #"Removed Columns"



if you want to do this in PQ, pls try this
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45Wck4sUjBU0lFKBGJDpVgdhEgSEBvBRYyAvGQgNkYRSQFiE7CIU2Z2KlhbKhCbogqlAbEZQgikMR2IzVGFMoDYQik2FgA=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Name = _t, column = _t, share = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Name", type text}, {"column", type text}, {"share", Int64.Type}}),
    Custom1 = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Name"}, {{"Count", each Table.AddIndexColumn(_, "Index", 1, 1, Int64.Type), type table}}),
    #"Expanded Count" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Custom1, "Count", {"column", "share", "Index"}, {"column", "share", "Index"}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded Count", "Custom", each Text.Remove([Name],{"0".."9"})),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom.1", each [a=Table.SelectRows(#"Added Custom",(x)=>x[Custom]=[Custom] and x[Index]=[Index]),
b=List.Sum(a[share]),
c=List.Count(a[Name]),
d=b/c]
[d])
in
    #"Added Custom1"


